# Text floats over figure in latex

Tags: graphics, floats

I just need to insert a figure in the latex document I am writing -nothing big.Problem is the text keeps floating over the figure and the figure is not centered.Here is my code

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\resizebox{20pt}{!}{\includegraphics{FigureStereo.jpg}}
\caption{Epipolar Geometry}
\label{fig:cclogo}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: In standard LaTeX this is usually caused by a wrong %BoundingBox in the (e)ps file included, but since you are using pdflatex w/ a JPG file this should not happen.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you mean that the text is put on top of the image? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment. The `\resizebox{20pt}{!}{\includegraphics{FigureStereo.jpg}}` can also be written as `\includegraphics[width=20pt]{FigureStereo.jpg}`.

Answer (score 8):

Your image might have the wrong bounding box information stored which makes LaTeX think it is smaller than it is. You could test it by using `\frame{\includegraphics[width=20pt]{FigureStereo.jpg}}` and see where the frame is drawn. Maybe opening the image in an image editor and saving it again will fix it.

If a wrong height is used you could add some vertical space to compensate for that. You need to try which amount is right:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \vspace{20pt}%
   \includegraphics[width=20pt]{FigureStereo.jpg}
   \caption{Epipolar Geometry}
   \label{fig:cclogo}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{Set2.png}
\caption{
Write the caption of the figure here.
}
\label{fig:obsssn}
\end{figure*}
```

Adding an star to the name of the element in latex does the work. This is because figure* creates a float environment for the figure in question which spans 2 columns. The element is centered on the page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please explain why the `*` does this? Perhaps you can complete your code snippet to be compilable and add then an screenshot to your answer ...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting the graphic in a tabular environment, inside the figure?

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tabular}{c} 
    \includegraphics[width=20pt]{FigureStereo.jpg} 
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Epipolar Geometry}
\label{fig:cclogo}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: and why should a tabular here make sense?

Comment: Don't know, the poster never responded if it helped or not.